# Dog with leukocytosis neutrophilia, treatments?

Tags: dogs, medicines

My dog can't move and if gets excited, it starts to shiver and tremble, also the dog has heart problems. Could this be the reason why my dog is not recovering?

We took the dog to a vet clinic and they said that they can't do anything because the dog can die at any moment, so my mom is taking care of the dog in these last 3 - 4 days and the dog is not recovering. even a dog veterinarian has came to my home and he gave to the dog: serum, antibiotics and vitamin

My mom is giving to the dog: soup and coconut water to hydrate

I don't know if the recovering can take long or we can't do anything to make recover my dog

Just posting here if there is a hope

**EDIT:**

Thanks to John Cavan for the reply, here more info about the exam:

Leukocytosis marked by neutrophilia

High values in:

- lymphocytes: 21100/mm<sup>3</sup>
- neutrophils: 90%, 18990

At the end of the exam it says:

- screening of hemoparasites:
- Woo: negative

I dont know how to read the result, it's in Spanish, my mom says that they did not mention a parasite.

Answer (score 2):

Neutrophilia is one of 5 forms of leukocytosis and it is basically a very high white blood cell count caused by parasitic infection, so treatments would normally be to deal with that. That presumes, of course, that this is a result of parasitic infection. Are you certain about this? Other forms of leukocytosis can have different causes, some far more serious.

It seems surprising that the vet would make that diagnosis and not look to treat your dog for the cause of this condition. There would seem to me that there should be more to this as the neutrophilia is more a symptom of something rather than the something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the question with bit more info about the exam result, I also was surprised with what the clinic vet said to my mom, don't much how to read the results

Comment: It's still not really saying much, at least not as far as I'm concerned. Infections, for example, can cause an elevated white blood cell count, but the elevated count isn't the problem, the infection is. That's the missing link for me.

Comment: Yes, there is no much info in the exam result, I think we have to take the dog to other vet clinics, I don't know if this is new for(vet clinic) them but even if it's new, why they don't investage, what is the problem? Big, big thanks for your reply

Comment: @tttony - If you can do a second opinion, then it's a good thing.